# Find proper subsets of a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this exercise:

Find proper subsets $A$, $B$, $C$ of a vector space $V$ over the field $\mathbb{R}^2$, so that $A + A \subset  A$, $B \subset B + B$ and $C + C = C$.

Questions:
Can I define the operation $+$ myself (f.e difference, or union etc) as long as $V$ still remains a vector space?

If yes: Since $A$, $B$, $C$ are subsets of the same vector space $V$, I can not define 3 different operations, right? One operation must be able to handle all those cases?

If yes: How is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by the field $\Bbb R^2$? I expect that for $A,B\subseteq V$, what is meant by $A+B$ is $\{a+b:a\in A\text{ and }b\in B\}$, so no, you probably don’t have any choice about what $+$ is.

Comment: Does $A=0$, $B=0$, $C=0$ work?

Comment: I assume you meant "over $\mathbb R$". I can't read the mind of whoever set the exercise, but it should be doable in $\mathbf R^2$ with the standard operations (note that all we're using is the vector space structure, and the isomorphism class of a vector space is determined by its dimension).

Comment: @Dylan, perhaps one is intended to interpret the inclusions as strict.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's a good point. Again, it's hard to decide for the OP what is meant. If this is the case, then I would not recommend a subspace for the first two parts!

Comment: @Peter: Change $0$ to $\{0\}$, and it would appear to work, unless the inclusions are intended to be strict.

Comment: I bet you can even find proper, non-trivial subsets $A,B,C$ of the integers such that $A+A$ is a proper subset of $A$, $B$ is a proper subset of $B+B$, and $C+C=C$.

Comment: Once again, hooray for $\subseteq,\subsetneq$ and for the extra joyous: $\subsetneqq$.

Comment: @Gerry: No question about it. And that does make it a worthwhile question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not defining a new operation, you are using the usual $+$ operation of $\mathbf{V}$.

If $\mathbf{V}$ is a vector space (or more generally, an abelian group), and $S$ and $T$ are subsets (not necessarily subspaces) of $\mathbf{V}$, then by definition 
$$S+T = \{s+t\mid s\in S,\ t\in T\}.$$

For $A$, you are looking for a subset with $A+A\subset A$, $A+A\neq A$.

- **Hint.** If $\mathbf{v}\neq\mathbf{0}$, and $\mathbf{v}\in A$, then $2\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v}\in A+A\subset A$, so $3\mathbf{v}=2\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v}\in A+A\subset A$, etc. So you will at least have $\{ n\mathbf{v}\mid n\text{ a positive integer}\}$ in $A$. Can that be *all* you have in $A$?

For $B$, you want a subset with $B\subset B+B$, $B\neq B+B$.

- **Hint.** Well, if you have $\mathbf{v}\in B$ as above, but $2\mathbf{v}\notin B$, then that will guarantee they are not equal. But $B=\{\mathbf{v}\}$ will not work, because then $\mathbf{v}\notin B+B = \{\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v}\} = \{2\mathbf{v}\}$. Maybe you can add stuff to $B$ to guarantee $\mathbf{v}\in B+B$? Careful, though, because now you'll need the thing you added to also be in $B+B$...

For $C$ you want something with $C+C=C$.

- **Hint.** What happens if you have all of $\mathbf{V}$?

Comment: Thanks, now that I know how + is defined, I can solve the rest.